# MYSQL Error Code: 1054 Unknown column '[NUMBER HERE]‬' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

There are a lot of results in Google related to Error 1054 but I cannot find my scenario (update using current value and adding some number):

```
UPDATE table
SET int_column=(int_column+1‬)
WHERE id > 100
```

The exact error is:

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column '1‬' in 'field list'

I think this could be related with some bug or missing feature in MySQL? because in my local MySQL the query runs without problem, but I get that error in my server.

EDIT: +1 is working! what is not working is +1296000‬ ! but if I type the number it works, it does not work when using "paste" (CTRL+V), maybe is pasting some weird character not visible, I don't know, I'm using SQLYog

Comment: I am guessing your code really uses backticks around the `1`.

Comment: *"I think this could be related with some bug or missing feature in MySQL? because in my local MySQL the query runs without problem, but I get that error in my server."*  Why does this sounds very contradictory unless offcource the remote server is not running MySQL or not the same version..

Comment: If you add a `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` structure from both the local and remote server and also run `SHOW VERSION()` on both and add that information to the question and read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) to provide example data and expected results aswell we can all give you a answer much more easy.

Comment: *"but I cannot find my scenario (update using current value and adding some number): "* @GordonLinoff for some reason this feels more like it should/could be `SET int_column = int_column + 1‬` instead.. Maybe because off the parenthesis the lexer/parser expects to find a subquery or corelated subquery there and not a SQL expression annymore maybe the lexer/parser is changed between in the MySQL versions or it is a bug i am not sure

Comment: @RaymondNijland, no, without parenthesis is not working either (I've tried without them first, getting the same error)

Comment: see mine other comment aswell..

Comment: Weird new info, actually the code from my example works! I mean if I use +1 it works, but my real example is +1296000‬ and that is not working! (see my edit and my answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would only get this error if you used:

```
UPDATE t
    SET int_column = (int_column +`1`‬)
    WHERE id > 100;
```

The backticks would force the constant to be interpreted as a column names.  Only use backticks to escape identifiers when necessary.  And then never give columns or tables names that need to be escaped, so you never need to escape their names.

Comment: No, I'm not using quotes or backticks, just a plain number

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with CTRL+V in SQLYog, I was pasting a number, maybe there was an invisible character or something weird like that (but I cannot see any extra whitespace etc).
Typing the number instead of using CTRL+V solves this silly problem

Comment: *"The problem was with CTRL+V in SQLYog"* well atleast i was "half" right it was a bug....  i have a feeling this is a character encoding issue somewhere in the SQLYog code you sure you connected with the correct charset connection to MySQL?  But maybe email the SQLYog devs about this problem and finding..